# アニメーションをキーフレーム指定で表示することはできますか？

Tags: unity3d

現在UnityにてTPS（サードパーソンシューティング）を作っています。

武器を構えた時に指定したキーフレームを表示したいのですがやり方が分かりません。マウスカーソルを動かすと顔がそこを追いかけてくれる…みたいな感じです。

分かりづらくて申し訳ございません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
Unityのバージョンは５です。

Comment: 視点を銃と一緒に動かしたいのか、アニメーションを特定のキーフレームにジャンプしたいのかどっちなんですかね。キーフレームという単語の理解に何か誤解があるんじゃ。

Answer (score 1):

アニメーションのキーフレームの取得は難しいですが、アニメーションを指定したフレームで表示するにはAnimationClipのframeRateから計算できます。

```
public class TestAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator    m_animator;

    void Awake()
    {
        m_animator  = GetComponent< Animator >();
    }

    public void SetAnimationFrame( int i_frame )
    {
        var clipInfoList    = m_animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo( 0 );
        var clip            = clipInfoList[ 0 ].clip;

        float time  = (float)i_frame / clip.frameRate;

        var stateInfo       = m_animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo( 0 );
        var animationHash   = stateInfo.shortNameHash;

        m_animator.Play( animationHash, 0, time );
    }
}
```

[image]

ただ、マウスカーソルの位置の方向に顔や銃が向くということをするのでしたら、アニメーションではなくスクリプト上で向きを計算してtransformのrotationなどを設定したほうがいいと思われます。